# How to resolve unlinked gradle project?

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

First I cloned [github repository](https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards) on my local machine. Then open Existing Android Studio project and selected  "example" folder from the repo on the local machine. Then I got:

[image: Issue] 
There were two events log : 
1. Unlinked Gradle project? 
2. Android Framework detected 
When I clicked on the link for linking to Gradle "Improt project from gradle" dialogue box opened and then I got "Resolve Error" dialogue box with error:

> Could not download artifact 'gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.4)': No cached version available for offline mode

My Android Studio version:

[image: Android Studio]

I have searched on the Google and stack Overflow, but can't find appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't import the Swipecards repo in Android Studio 1.0.1 using gradle.

This project is using this unsupported version of gradle-plugin.

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.4'
```

I suggest you cloning the repo locally changing these values:   `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'` in build.gradle    `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip` in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties