# Project cannot run

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I fix this? It is a must to update the android studio? Thanks :)

[image]

**EventLog**

```
7:12:24 PM Unlinked Gradle project?
           Import Gradle project, this will also enable Gradle Tool Window.
           Don't want to see the message for the project again: press here.
7:12:24 PM Plugin Error
           Problems found loading plugins:

           Plugin "SDK Updater" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
           Plugin "Android NDK Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
           Plugin "Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
           Plugin "Google Cloud Testing" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
           Plugin "Google Services" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
           Disable not loaded plugins
           Enable Android Support
           Open plugin manager
7:12:24 PM Platform and Plugin Updates: A new version of Android Studio is available! (show balloon)
```

Comment: Does anyone faced this before?

Comment: Open android sdk-manager and check if there are any updates available

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207662/how-to-resolve-unlinked-gradle-project

Comment: @DhruvGohil Just now i accidentally turned off my laptop.When I restart, it becomes like this

Comment: @BhaveshPatadiya I know this question has been asked before, but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: which android studio version are u currently using?

Comment: check the path of  sdk and ndk  that you have given is correct and try to clean the project before run it

Comment: @DhruvGohil yeah, there are some updates available. After done updating, will the problem solved?

Comment: yeah,It can.you should update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your LOGCAT Shows

> Plugin "SDK Updater" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support"
>   is disabled.
>              Plugin "Android NDK Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
>              Plugin "Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
>              Plugin "Google Cloud Testing" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
>              Plugin "Google Services" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
>              Disable not loaded plugins
>              Enable Android Support
>              Open plugin manager 7:12:24 PM Platform and Plugin Updates: A new version of Android Studio is available! (show balloon)

You can switch to that channel (if necessary) and check for updates via **`Help > Check for Update... (on OSX, look in the Android Studio menu)`**. This will download and install a patch rather than download a full IDE image. Note however that if you do this, you will replace your existing(if)1.4 installation, which you may not want to do. Just keep 1.4 and 1.5 Preview installed side by side; they already use separate settings and cache directories.

So

1. Update your **Android Studio** *(SDK & Repository too)*
2. ***Restart And Sync With Gradle***